# Table that Fills 100% Parent Height with Fixed Header/Footer

Tags: html, css, html-table

This question has been asked a million times and been given equally as many different solutions, but I can't seem to find one that pertains to my situation, hence why I'm asking again.

I want to create a table that fills 100% of its parent container, with a locked header and footer. Finding a clean, easy solution would likely result in knighthood, so I know it's not a simple task and it may require Javascript - this is fine.

Here's the layout I have: **two fixed left menus, a dynamic width content area with two headers, and a table that fills 100% of the content area with a fixed header and footer.**

[image]

[**- - Here's a Fiddle to play with. - -**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhKbr/6/)

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="page-content" id="grid-container">
    <div class="table-container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First</th>
                    <th>Last</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jon</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>Indianapolis</td>
                    <td>Indiana</td>
                </tr>
                [...etc...]
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Last</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>State</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.page-content {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.table-container {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid green;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
#grid-container table thead {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

#grid-container table thead>tr {
    display:block;
}

#grid-container table tbody {
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:500px;
}
```

**Question:** How can I stick the header and footer to the top and bottom of the content area (and have them move if the browser is resized vertically), and make the tbody scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using javascript. Here's what I did:

Essentially I calculate the content space for the table (minus header, subheader, and filters), then I stacked three tables on top of one another: one for the header, one for the body, and one for the footer. I set the body height to the content area height that I calculated, minus the header and footer height.

```
$(function() {
    drawTable();

    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        drawTable();
    });
});

function drawTable() {

    // Heights for calculating content area
    var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
    var toolbars = $("#toolbars").outerHeight();
    var filters = $("#filters").outerHeight();

    // Total height of the table header and footer
    var headerFooter = $("#grid-container thead").outerHeight() + $("#grid-container tfoot").outerHeight();

    // Size the parent containers based on the remaining area
    $(".page-content").height(windowHeight - toolbars);
    $("#grid-container").height(windowHeight - toolbars - filters - headerFooter);  

    // Set cell widths to be the same for the header, content, and footer
    $("#grid-container tbody td, #grid-container tfoot th, #grid-container thead th").width(100/$("#grid-container thead th").size() + "%");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Do you have a complete css and javascript for the 100% height fixed header and footer?  can you update in the fiddel?

Answer (score 0):

```
.header
{
 position:fixed;
 z-index: 100;
}

.container {
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```