# Sticky Table Header with 100% height "panes"

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Background:**
I am using CSS to create a web app like experience, where everything on the page is always visible, and only certain `panes` are scrollable. I now have a need to expand this to tables. I want the table header to always stay visible (and sometimes a footer) but the table body should be scrollable only.

What I have done so far is apply a "pane" class to the `thead` and `tfoot`, and then made the `tbody` auto fill the height and then make it scrollable. All of this works except that the thead, tbody, and tfoot are no longer 100% width. This method seems to get me the closest to what I want.

**Fiddle:**
I have a JSFiddle that gets me close, it also demonstrates the code I'm using to create the fixed and scrollable `panes`. http://jsfiddle.net/va4HF/1/

**Requirements:** Ideally I would like to keep my `pane` css as it is, but adapt it when a table is needed. I'd also like to keep this CSS only.

The following code is my proof-of-concept code, and includes the Pane CSS as well.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="pane top">Top</div>
    <div class="pane middle">
        <table>
            <thead class="pane table-head">
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="pane table-body fill">
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="pane table-foot">
                <tr>
                    <th>Footer</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pane bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:content-box\9; /* Fix for IE9 sizing */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Fix for firefox sizing */
}
.column {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.pane {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fill {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
.top {
    background:pink;
    height: 20%;
    top:0;
}
.middle {
    background:red;
    top:20%;
    bottom:50px;
}
.table-head {
    height: 40px;
    top:0;
}
.table-body {
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
}
.table-foot {
    height: 40px;
    bottom:0;
}
.bottom {
    background:orange;
    height: 50px;
    bottom:0;
}
table thead tr, table tfoot tr {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
table tbody tr {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
table td, table th {padding:10px; color:#fff;}

/* Fix for Safari scrollbars (also styles Chrome scrollbars) */
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar {-webkit-appearance: none;width: 10px;}
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);border-radius: 0px;}
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 0px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);}
```

**Research**: 
Someone else has asked this with a similar situation at [Table that Fills 100% Parent Height with Fixed Header/Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010762/table-that-fills-100-parent-height-with-fixed-header-footer) but never got a good response and ended up going with Javascript, but I would like to try and find a CSS solution. Or at the very least a simpler Javascript solution then what he used (avoid having to overlay three tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research to figure out all of my options for this I opted for going with separate tables for the header, body and footer and I surround each table with a div. I then style that div as a "pane". As long as the columns in the header table and the body table are set as the same width, they will line up.

There was some cleanup I had to do, one of which resulted in needing to keep the vertical scrollbar always showing, and then add a margin to the header and footer tables so that if the body starts to scroll or not, the headers will always line up.

It would be something like this:

```
    <div class="pane table-head">
        <table>
            <thead class="">
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pane table-body fill">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
                ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pane table-foot">
        <table>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Footer</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

See updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bluecaret/va4HF/5/

This still isn't an ideal solution, I may end up ditching this and go with Fabio's solution of a div based table, although I can see potential issues with that as well based on some tests. For now this is what I'll be sticking with.

Answer (score 0):

well, the first question is why are you using tables at all, but just in case use this:

```
table, th{width:100% !important; min-width:240px; }
```

where min-width is the minimum width for the table

Then again, you really should use divs: less, easier markups, no problems like this

Comment: I'm using tables because i have tabular data that I need to insert. if you look at the fiddle I'm using divs for the rest of the panes. And thanks but that still doesn't work. Just made the `th` be the min width while the tbody is still short

Comment: ah, then you add tbody (and/or tr or td if you need it) to the declaration, thought it was only the th. Also, tabular data doesn't need tables at all, you can use divs and apply "display: table" (see full posibilities at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp ) . I'm mentioning this because if you need to use responsive layouts, it will save your life, believe me

Comment: Still doesn't work. It only goes to the min-width size and stops. I even added all the table elements to it and same thing. And making min-width 100% doesn't work either. See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bluecaret/va4HF/3/ I'll look into using Div's for tabular data, but I'd still prefer to use tables if possible, makes it easier for the others on my team to work with who arn't savvy in CSS. Thanks.

Comment: you're using the exact same code I gave you, please read this: **where min-width is the minimum width for the table** so if your table is going to be 600px width, you'll add 600px min-width: I tested it on your fiddle and works like a charm

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my description. I need the table to be 100% width, not a set pixel width. Meaning, if viewed on a large monitor, the table should be stretched to fill the width and height which would potentially make it 1000px, or on a smaller monitor, 600px. Setting the min-width to 600px will keep it at that size even on the larger screens.

Comment: well, then the obvious answer is NOT to use tables and use divs, but, just to fix this specific scenario: add a div that acts as a th, a div as a table container and a footer div. Like this: <div id="tablecontainer"><div id="tablehead">your head</div><div id="tablebody">your table, no th, just rows</div><div id="tablefoot">your foot</div></div> . Then you add an overflow:auto to #tablebody and that's it.